# How to get table row values with Power Automate Desktop?

Tags: power-automate

Power Automate UI Picker doesn't pick contents of a table in desktop application.

I try to select table rows with mouse but UI Picker see only common table group item. Not seeing separate table rows, etc.
[image]
How to do that?